# New repository works on bitbucket, but there is a problem on github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Both bitbucket and github give the same instructions for the new repository.

```
git init  
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourLogin/yourProject.git  
commit something
git push -u origin master
```

After executing these commands, my project appears on the bitbucket, but in case GitHub, i got the response:

```
Push failed: Failed with error: unable to access `'https://github.com/yourLogin/yourProject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`
```

For sure, I was looking for a stackoverflow response and people recommend using ssh, but I do not want to avoid the problem, just solve it, if github allows using https, I want to use it :)

Does anyone know why github causes such problems? What could be the reason ?
Of course I create repository first on github.

Comment: I’d suggest using SSH over HTTPS

Comment: I want to use https, just like with bitbucket :) why downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 is the status code for "unauthorized" - you are not permitted to do what you're trying to do. You may need to put your username in the URL (`https://user@github.com/owner/repo.git`) when adding the remote, or modify the existing remote (with `git remote set-url`) to include the username.